# Getting IIS Server directory path

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis

I am trying to get the IIS server directory path from another computer to download few files from there.

using codes like this..

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile("//serverpath", "a.exe");
}
```

I would like to download the files from the directory shown in the picture!
[image: server directory]

That is the server computer and I'll be putting some exe files in that directory .I would now like to download the files that i put in that directory to the client computer I'm am using. How should I put the serverpath?? Agent folder is an virtual directory.

Answer (score 0):

If this is asp.net mvc there is direct support for this with `FileResult`, and Controller has a set of helpers:

In your action:

```
return File(filename, contentType);
```

Comment: i guess i'm making a bold assumption this is asp.net mvc